# Fibonacci Sequence - Starts at a specific # in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
//var myInputNumber=10;

function fibonacci(num) {
    let fib = [1,1];
    for (let i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
      fib.push(fib[i-1] + fib[i-2]);
    }
    return fib;
  }

 console.log(fibonacci(10));
```

Complete javascript newbie here.  I need help with a homework project.  I have this work and displays up to the x (for easier display) Fibonacci numbers.

Here is the results from the above code: [ 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89 ]

What I want to be able to do is specify the starting number/point (>=10, for example), and have it only display numbers from that point going forward.

So if my input number is 10, I want this result [ 13, 21, 34, 55, 89 ].

Comment: Do you want to specify both a starting point and the number of numbers of return?

Comment: How many numbers "going forward"?  It's an infinite sequence.

Comment: @Pointy I think he means that the `num` parameter keeps saying how many numbers from the sequence to get, the only difference, is that the responce should filter numbers below some other number `k`

Comment: adding this works for the code above.                                                      
    return fib.filter(function(item) {
    return item > num.  I'll just keep it like this for now, many thanks for all of the quick responses.

Comment: Well I'm sure there are all sorts of reasonable approaches, but the OP has not clearly described what the goal is and what the problem is with the posted code.

Comment: @Pointy, I agree. The OP is asking for a solution to a programming assignment and seems as no research was done to try and find a solution. MBrewster, I suggest reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use array `filter` and in the callback function return those element which are greater than the number passed as argument

```js
function fibonacci(num) {
  let fib = [1, 1];
  for (let i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
    fib.push(fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2]);
  }
  return fib.filter(function(item) {
    return item > num
  });
}

console.log(fibonacci(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

just add another variable then

```
function fibonacci(num) {
let result = [];
let fib = [1,1];
  for (let i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
    let temp = fib[i-1] + fib[i-2];
    fib.push(temp);
    if(result>=num)
      result.push(temp)
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to define a limit to stop. The rest is pretty much similar to your existing code

```
function fibonacci(num, limit) {
    let fib = [1,1];
    for (let i = num; i <= limit; i++) {
      fib.push(fib[i-1] + fib[i-2]);
    }
    return fib;
}
```